# Deploying OFBiz on External Application Server

Tags: tomcat, deployment, jboss, ofbiz

Any one succeeded in deploying OFBiz on external application server Tomcat/ Jboss.

I tried to install ofbiz on Tomcat and Jboss in both cases i am facing issues.
I used the following configurations to install ofbiz on appservers:

OFBiz Version: 10.04

Tomcat:6

JBoss 5.0.1

If any one having idea on deploying ofbiz on external app server, please reply to me...

Comment: I am also looking for this. But, my research so far, points that this is not possible. I will let you know if I find any. In the meantime, please post here if you get any clues.

Answer (score 3):

I just managed to deploy ofbiz in Tomcat 7.  Following were the steps that i followed.

- generated the setup for tomcat6 using `java -jar ofbiz.jar -setup tomcat6`.
- manually merged the `catalina.bat, catalina.properties, server.xml` files
- i had to change all `file://` references to `file:////` in `catalina.properties`.  found this solution in a forum.  this was leading to a catalina startup exception
- next i found out that the webapplication deployments were failing as none of the `component://` resource paths were getting resolved.  found that this was because the Component Container was not getting initailized.  As a result of this even scanning for entity xml files was failing and hence the schema was not getting created automatically in the database.  this initialization happens through the `org.ofbiz.base.start.Start` class this is called when `java -jar ofbiz.jar` is called.... i solved this issue with a somewhat dirty workaround. I created a custom `ServletContextListener`that in turn calls `new Start().init(args, true)` where args is a string array with just one entry `start`.  I had to register this Listener in every web.xml file, i basically did a find and append my listener after the entry `<listener><listener-class>org.ofbiz.webapp.control.ControlEventListener</listener-class></listener>` in all the web.xmls as tomcat can load webapps in any order and we dont know which will be loaded first.  to ensure the listener only does its job once, i simply used a boolean static flag.  I picked `ControlEventListener` as a starting point so that i could do a simple global regex find and replace across `web.xml` files using a text editor
- the next problem i faced was that inspite of setting ofbiz.home system property, it was getting ignored, set this is start.properties in `framework\start\src\org\ofbiz\base\start\start.properties`
- And the final issue i had to sort out was to prevent the init method from attempting to load the Catalina container.  I solved this by simply commenting out the catalina container entry in `framework\base\config\ofbiz-containers.xml`

And Success.  Hope this helps someone!

Comment: What do you mean wit "manually merged the catalina.bat,catalina.properties,server.xml" ?

Comment: Compare the usual out-of-the-box versions of these tomcat files with the ofbiz generated ones and decide what you need and what you don't. It should be fairly obvious if you are comfortable with Web applications and java class path

Comment: I am getting following error. Error: Could not find or load main class  -Dofbiz.home=E:.Code.ofbiz

Comment: Right on the first step i get `Exception in thread "main" org.ofbiz.base.start.StartupException: Couldn't not fetch config instance (Cannot load configuration properties : org/ofbiz/base/start/-setup.properties)`, apparently OfBiz doesn't recognize the `-setup` command.

Answer (score 1):

i succeeded to deploy both OFBiz 9.04 and 10.04 to external tomcat v6.0.16
please, view this post
[deploying OFBIz 10.04 to tomcat 6](http://i4fteam.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/deploy-ofbiz-to-external-tomcat-6/)

Answer (score 0):

I have reported it in JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-4682

With this issue unresolved, you need to deploy any webapp you under ofbiz. A user on the mailing list suggested I use two tomcat instances and just change the port.

There seems no interest in fixing it. Maybe if this issues receives more votes, it will be considered for fixing.

sorry not much help !